# R - loop even for variable

Tags: r, regex, date

How to use this command in R for a range of numbers?

```
PR01 <- Pra_Ruz[grep("-01-", Pra_Ruz$Date), ]
```

I mean

```
PR01 <- Pra_Ruz[grep("-01-", Pra_Ruz$Date), ]
PR02 <- Pra_Ruz[grep("-02-", Pra_Ruz$Date), ]
PR03 <- Pra_Ruz[grep("-03-", Pra_Ruz$Date), ]
PR04 <- Pra_Ruz[grep("-04-", Pra_Ruz$Date), ]
....
```

Comment: Are you trying to split the data based on months?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to split the data based on months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) with expected output.

Consider this as your data -

```
Pra_Ruz <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c('2012-01-31', '2020-12-28', 
        '2015-10-11', '2014-04-16', '2016-03-22')), a = 1:5)

Pra_Ruz
#        Date a
#1 2012-01-31 1
#2 2020-12-28 2
#3 2015-10-11 3
#4 2014-04-16 4
#5 2016-03-22 5
```

You can specify the range in regex using `[1-4]`

```
Pra_Ruz[grep("-0[1-4]-", Pra_Ruz$Date), ]

#        Date a
#1 2012-01-31 1
#4 2014-04-16 4
#5 2016-03-22 5
```

Another option -

If these are date objects you can extract the month value from it and then subset.

```
Pra_Ruz[as.integer(format(Pra_Ruz$Date, '%m')) %in% 1:4, ]
```

---

If you want to split the datasets in multiple individual dataframes

```
data <- split(Pra_Ruz, format(Pra_Ruz$Date, '%m'))
names(data) <- paste0('PR', names(data))
list2env(data, .GlobalEnv) #Not recommended, do only if necessary.
```

Comment: Thanks and how to save the split data to variables?

Comment: @Anna-Kat See the updated answer.